# Whether loop variables are always freshly created

Tags: chapel

In the following code, I'm using the variable name `n` for both a local variable and a loop counter:

```
proc main()
{
    var n = 700;
    writeln( "n (before loop) = ", n );

    for n in 1..3 {
        writeln( "n = ", n );
    }

    writeln( "n (after loop) = ", n );
}
```

and the result is

```
n (before loop) = 700
n = 1
n = 2
n = 3
n (after loop) = 700
```

Does this mean that the `for` loop always creates a new loop variable, in a way similar to `for (int n = 1; n <= 3; n++)` rather than `for (n = 1; n <= 3; n++)` (in C-like languages)?

(Background) I was playing with the following code using `ref`, and since the loop did not change the value of `baa` in the outer scope, I imagined that `b` is probably created as a new variable...

```
proc main()
{
    var baa: int = 700;
    ref b = baa;

    writeln( "baa (before loop) = ", baa );

    for b in 1..3 {
        writeln( "b = ", b, " baa = ", baa );
    }

    writeln( "baa (after loop) = ", baa );
}
```

Result:

```
baa (before loop) = 700
b = 1 baa = 700
b = 2 baa = 700
b = 3 baa = 700
baa (after loop) = 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the for loop always creates a new loop variable, in a way similar to `for (int n = 1; n <= 3; n++)` rather than `for (n = 1; n <= 3; n++)` (in C-like languages)?

Yes, that's right.  Chapel's `for`, `forall`, and `coforall` loops each declare new index variables for their iterations.  In the `forall` and `coforall` cases this is done out of necessity since different tasks will be executing different iterations and each will need its own copy of the index variable.  Our `for` loops adopt the same strategy for consistency and convenience.  If you want to modify an outer variable within a Chapel [`co`]`for`[`all`] loop, you would need to do it in the loop's body or iterator expression.

The compiler could (and perhaps should) emit a warning for cases like yours in which a loop variable shadows a variable at the same scope, to avoid confusion.  If you'd like to advocate for this behavior, please consider filing a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues) for it.

Comment: Also see: https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/users-guide/base/forloops.html#for-loop-index-variables

Comment: Thanks very much! (and the linked page is precisely what I should have read...)