# Invalid use of a type field or array element as a loop counter

Tags: chapel

In the following code, I have tried using a field variable (of class or record) or an array element directly as a loop counter, but this was illegal ("error: invalid index expression"). Is this simply because the loop counter must be a scalar variable?

```
class Cls {
    var n: int;
}

proc main()
{
    var x = new Cls( 100 );
    var k: [1..10] int;

    for x.n in 1..3 do      // error: invalid index expression
        writeln( x.n );

    for k[1] in 1..3 do     // error: invalid index expression
        writeln( k[1] );
}
```

On the other hand, if I create a reference to `x.n`, it compiled successfully but `x` in the outer scope was not modified. Is this because a new loop variable named `n` is created in the for-loop? (which I'm afraid is almost the same as my another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948407/whether-loop-variables-are-always-freshly-created)...)

```
proc main()
{
    var x = new Cls( 100 );
    ref n = x.n;

    for n in 1..3 do
        writeln( n );

    writeln( "x = ", x );   // x = {n = 100}
}
```

If a loop variable is created independently, I guess something like "var x.n = ..." might happen (internally) if I write `for x.n in 1..3`, which seems really invalid (because it means that I'm trying to declare a loop variable with a name `x.n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that this relates to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948407/whether-loop-variables-are-always-freshly-created).  As described there, Chapel's for-loops create new index variables to store the values yielded by the iterator expression(s), so a loop like `for i in ...` results in a new variable `i` being declared rather than using an existing variable or expression.  If you think the error message should be improved to make this clearer, please consider suggesting a new wording in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/issues).

Note that in addition to single variable names, a loop can also use tuples of index variables to capture the results of a zippered iteration or an iterand that yields tuple values.  For instance, the values of the following zippered iteration can either be captured as scalar values `i` and `j`:

```
for (i,j) in zip(1..3, 2..6 by 2) do  // store values in 'i' and 'j' respectively
  writeln((i,j));
```

or as a single variable of tuple type:

```
for ij in zip(1..3, 2..6 by 2) do  // store values in 2-tuple 'ij'
  writeln(ij);
```

Similarly, when iterating over something that yields tuple values, such as a multidimensional index set, the results can be captured either as scalar values or tuples:

```
const D = {1..3, 0..2};  // declare a 2D rectangular domain

for (i,j) in D do   // store indices in new scalars 'i' and 'j'
  writeln((i,j));

for ij in D do      // store indices in new 2-tuple 'ij'
  writeln(ij);
```

More complex iterators that return larger, or nested tuples, can similarly be de-tupled or not in the declaration of the index variable(s).

Comment: Thanks very much, now things are clear to me (i.e., a new loop variable is created for for-loops). By the way, this syntax ("for ij in D do") is one of my most favorite ones in Chapel (because it simplifies  multi-dimensional loops :-) I think the error message is no problem because we can understand that it is not allowed (syntactically).

Comment: Yes, the multi-dimensional loop support is pretty great.  My favorite example was when a summer intern wrote an AMR framework that was rank-independent so that he could debug it in a 1D run and then run it in production in 2D, 3D, nD, ...  (https://github.com/chapel-lang/chapel/tree/master/test/studies/amr)